# webflux resources router doesn't work as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I"m trying something very simple with webflux - serving a static page

**Folder structure**

```
-- resources
  -- public
     myPage.html  
    -- css
       style.css
```

**Routers**

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> htmlRouter(@Value("classpath:/public/myPage.html") Resource html) {
    return route(GET("/path/myPage"),
        request -> ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(html));
 }

@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> imgRouter() {
  return RouterFunctions.resources("/**", new ClassPathResource("/public/"));
}
```

**Html snippet**

```
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  ...
</header>
```

calling `http://example.com/path/myPage` does serve the page, but am getting 404 for the css part

running on `logging.level.org.springframework.web: TRACE`, I can see that `styles.css` is being resolved to `/path/css/style.css` and not searched under `/public/css/style.css` which is my issue.

```
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET &quot;/path/css/style.css&quot; [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML snippet, you should use an absolute path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Using a relative path `css/styles.css` lets your browser think that it should request for a resource, relative to the current page, so `/path/css/style.css`. The issue is not in your router, but in your template directly.